# AWS Cloudformation: Reuse result of Fn::FindInMap

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

In template.yml, a mapping regionToDomainMap is defined and I am accessing that in multiple places with `{Fn::FindInMap: [regionToDomainMap, Ref: Region, "regionToDomain"]}`.

Is there a way to assign this to a variable and use that instead of using this long form everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there are **no variables** in CloudFormation (CFN), so you can't shorten your map use through variables. However, if this or similar constructs are used very often you could consider developing a basic find-and-replace [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) in CFN.

You could also have a look at AWS provided and managed [AWS::Include transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html) which could also be helpful in your case.